# Can I write a catch clause similar to abbreviated function templates?

Tags: c++, templates, try-catch, c++-concepts, c++17

At the top of my program, I have an exception handler.
It looks something like this:

```
try{
    //majority of program
}
catch(...){
   Handle_All_Exceptions();
}


void Handle_All_Exceptions(){
   try{throw;}
   catch(TypeA const& e){Handle(e)       ;}
   catch(TypeB const& e){Handle(e)       ;}
   catch(TypeC const& e){Handle(e)       ;}
   catch(TypeD const& e){Handle(e)       ;}
   catch(...)           {Handle_Unknown();}

}

void Handle(TypeA const& e){
    //...
}
void Handle(TypeB const& e){
    //...
}
void Handle(TypeC const& e){
    //...
}
void Handle(TypeD const& e){
    //...
}
void Handle_Unknown(){
    //...
}
```

As I obtain more an more exception types,
I'd like to take a more generic approach.
**How can I apply generic programming to the** `Handle_All_Exceptions` **function?**

---

Would something like this be possible in newer versions of C++?

```
catch(auto e){Handle(e)};
catch(...){Handle_Unknown();}
```

Comment: Do your exceptions have a common base class?

Comment: @robert, No, but I suppose inheriting std::exception may be a better approach.

Comment: @TrevorHickey suggest you consider std::runtime_error for your base class: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/runtime_error

Answer (score 0):

It’s not possible without significant changes to the language and its exception system. While catch-clause handlers and function parameters may look like syntactically similar, they work quite differently. Consider:

```
struct up {};
struct down { constexpr down(up) noexcept {} };

void func(down const&) {}
void except()
{
    try {
        throw up {};
    } catch(down const&) {}
}

int main()
{
    func(up {}); // fine
    except();    // exception `up` escapes
}
```

[<kbd>Coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/25f7d9544eba4276)

In other words, a `down const&` parameter will accept anything that is *convertible* to `down`, while a `down const&` handler will bind to exception objects of type `down` or of a type unambiguously, publicly *derived* from `down`.

The big difference here is that relationships of the form 'is convertible to' can take many forms. In our example we used a conversion constructor, but we could have instead used a conversion operator inside `up`. Whereas 'is (publicly, unambiguously) derived from' can only be opted-in in one straightforward fashion, and at exactly one location program-wide: wherever the derived type is defined. This is important when we keep into account separate compilation. Consider the following program:

```
// a.cpp

// defined in b.cpp
void throws() noexcept(false);

template<typename X>
concept bool Fooable = requires(X x) { x.foo(); }

int main()
{
    try {
      throws();

      // imaginary syntax for catching models of a concept
    } catch(Fooable const&) {}
}

// b.cpp

// defined in c.cpp
struct other;

struct model {
    void foo() {}
    other* foo(int) { return nullptr; }
    void bar() {}
};

void throws() noexcept(false)
{ throw model {}; }

// c.cpp omitted
```

When `b.cpp` is compiled, the compiler has no way of knowing that `a.cpp` will ask the question 'Is that object you’re throwing capable of `x.foo()`?'. Should it pessimistically record that fact nonetheless (in the same way under the current rules the 'is-derived from' relationship, if any, is recorded somewhere)? Should it also record the fact that `model` is capable of `x.bar()`, even though the full program doesn’t need it? What if `Fooable` instead tested for `x.foo(0)->baz()`? Where, when, and how would that be recorded if `other` were defined such that the expression made sense? Note how `model` and `other` are defined separately and each don’t know (much) about the other.

Certainly what you ask for is not straight impossible, but I hope we can agree it looks quite different to the system we have now and would require a lot of effort before it would work. Under current rules generic programming for exceptions can only go so far, using old-fashioned class hierarchies is the path of least resistance.